# React-native facebook login shows blank screen / white screen

Tags: facebook, react-native, expo

facebook: ~5.0.1`and`expo: 33.0.0`

```
  onFacebookSignIn = async () => {
        try {
            const {
                type,
                token,
            } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(facbookAppId, {
                permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],
                browser: 'browser'
            });
            if (type === 'success') {
                const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
                Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
            } else {
                console.log('cancel');
            }
        } catch ({ message }) {
            alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
        }
    }
```

**on click of a button it opens facebook login page login via my email and password works fine but in case of login via install facebook app, it takes me to next allow page but than next page show blank:(

i have spent couple of days on this on and off, thankyou.
[image: blank screen after giving permission for my app to facebook] 
 screen[image: login page]**

Comment: Try to work with package  expo-facebook  version 7.0.0 and use  import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook'; look at documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/

Answer (score 0):

Since Facebook actually opens and you are prompt with the login page then it is most probably that you make a mistake setting up your Facebook app on your Facebook developer account.

1. Follow [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps#register) to set your Facebook app correctly
2. Make sure to set `host.exp.Exponent` for your app field iOS Bundle ID
3. Make sure to set `rRW++LUjmZZ+58EbN5DVhGAnkX4=` for your app field Android key hash

Please follow [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/facebook/) since you are using expo SDK 33